# Архитектура web-приложений для чайников

Tags: архитектура, java-ee, java

Собрался вот написать небольшое web-приложение на JavaEE (форум или гостевую) и думаю, как это сделать, так сказать, по фэншую... Насколько я понимаю, выглядеть (в рамках mvc) это должно так: welocme-page.jsp (по умолчанию, а также данные со всех форм идут на неё), с которой редиректится на сервлет-контроллер, который анализирует, что пришло post/get-методом, и вызывает соответствующий метод из модели, по завершению которого из этого сервлета редиректится на соответсвующую jsp-страницу, которая в свою очередь запросит данные из модели. Насколько такой подход грамотен и как на самом деле надо?

Опыт написания форума был ещё в школе много лет назад, но на php (по этому так и хочется проводить аналогию).

Так же есть ещё небольшой вопрос из этой серии: в php были переменные, в которых хранились данные post- и get-запросов, которые я мог в любой последовательности обрабатывать, так вот: как быть в Java, если был post-запрос из некой формы с указанным адресам вида site.ru/?var1=1&var2=2 (т.е., иными словами, совершён запрос с передачей и post- и get-параметров одновременно)?

Comment: just do it

Comment: P.S. Давайте без оскорблений пожалуйста.

Comment: А зачем вам писать форум или гостевую на JavaEE? :)

Comment: Потому, что я сел изучать его :)

Comment: @Andrey759, @brizz, может, хоть вы мне расскажете, что пишут на JavaEE?

Answer (score 4):

По фэншую обычно берется некий фреймворк, который реализует указанный вами паттерн MVC (кстати, он не единственный - есть и другие подходы).

Самый простой фреймворк c MVC, который доступен для понимания начинающим и без лишних наворотов, это [Struts](http://struts.apache.org/) - рекомендую начать с него.

Answer (score 0):

Для Вашей задачи подойдет фреймворк `JavaServer Faces` на базе которого сделан [Primefaces](https://www.primefaces.org/), или его аналоги.